# How to set ACL Deny All flag to false in the bluemix secure-gateway client

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Given that I want to start my secure-gateway docker client using the SG docker command line interface, and I want to allow access to all on-premise IPs via ACL command option, what do I specify on the SG client command line?

For example for the starting SG client docker command line like this:

docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client TOxuMfbPxxxx_prod_ng --service --name=mysg_client --sectoken eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCxxxxxxxxxOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb25maWd1cmF0aW9uX2lkIjoiVE94dU1mYlBjRXhfcHJvZF9uZyIxxxxxxlvbiI6InVzLXNvdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNDQyODcxMjk5fQ.7kxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0

Answer (score 3):

Access Control List commands

The supported ACL commands are:

```
acl allow hostname:port
acl deny hostname:port
no acl hostname:port
no acl
show acl
```

The forms where you have left out either a hostname or port implies all hostnames or ports. For example, the following is an ACL rule to allow all hostnames for port 22.

```
acl allow :22
```

The following is an ACL rule to allow all hostnames for all ports, essentially disabling ACL support, this is not recommended.

```
acl allow :
```

The 'show acl' command will of course clearly show the currently set ACL or provide a message on the overall setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of the ACL commands and other related information in the [Setting up a Secure Gateway](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_022.html) topic within the product documentation.